# Which freelance sites are recommended to find WordPress developers/programmers, etc

Tags: customization

I've been using drupal for a few years and it's overkill. I want to pay someone to migrate my content (blog posts and pages) over to wordpress without spending more than is necessary.

Is there a specific site such as odesk, elance, guru, rentacoder, etc. that is popular with wordpress programmers and tends to have the best rates? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oDesk has lot of WordPress developers that could migrate your site from Drupal to WordPress at low cost. I like oDesk because it takes screen shots every few minutes as the contractor's work on your job. You can monitor their work very effectively, particularly if you understand the work being done.

In this case if you don't want any changes to the site, you could easily post this as a fixed price job, which would probably give you the lowest cost. Looking at the numerous other WordPress jobs listed on oDesk is a good way to see how to post your job - a well crafted job post will get you a better result.

On a practical note I would suggest you consider selecting a WordPress theme you would like use before posting your migration job on oDesk. Take this chance to update your site and migrate to a solid, well supported WordPress theme which meets your functional and visual requirements.

If the theme you select needs to customised in any way to meet your requirements, make sure the developer does this via a child theme, so that you can have easy upgrading of the parent theme.

Comment: Good points about organizing the theme beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Most of those sites allow you to search for freelancers without opening an account to see how many/what quality WP consultants are there, their rank, feedback, etc. Elance seems to be the busiest. Rates are all set by the individual.

http://jobs.wordpress.net/ is free to list, but there is no feedback or ranking system.

Answer (score 0):

WPCandy [just opened](http://wpcandy.com/announces/the-launch-of-wpcandy-pros) a new site where WordPress professionals can list themselves: [WPCandy Pros](http://wpcandy.com/pros).